# Gstreamer video output position tracking and seeking

Tags: linux, camera, gstreamer

I am using gstreamer (gst-launch) to capture camera and save the stream as both video and image frame. The problem of the pipeline is, when the pipeline finishes (by interrupt) the video record, it can not support position tracking and seeking. Hence, video is played in vlc player with unknown lenght. I think problem is at the pipeline itself. How can we achieve to support position tracking and seeking.

Here below you can see the gstreamer pipeline code:

```
gst-launch -v --gst-debug-level=0 \
       v4l2src device=/dev/video0 \
       ! videorate \
       ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=320, height=240, framerate=5/1 \
       ! tee name=tp
       tp. \
       ! queue \
       ! videobalance saturation=0.0 \
       ! textoverlay halign=left valign=top text="(c)PARK ON OM " shaded-background=true \
       ! clockoverlay halign=right valign=top time-format="%D %T "  text="Date:" shaded-background=true \
       ! queue \
       ! ffmpegcolorspace \
       ! ffenc_mpeg4 \
       ! avimux \
       ! filesink location=/ram/pmc/recordCAM1.mp4 \
       tp. \
       ! queue \
       ! jpegenc \
       ! multifilesink location=/ram/pmc/webcam1.jpeg &
```

The explanation of the pipeline is like below:

```
                                                        ______________  ________  _______     ________________
                                                        |convert into|->|append|->|encode| -> |save file as    | 
_________________    ________________   _____________   | grayscale  |  |text  |  |ffenc |    | recordCAM1.mp4 |
| use /dev/video |-> |set framerate |-> |multiplexer|->
| as input source|   |and resolution|   | named tp  |->
                                                        __________  _________________
                                                        |jpeg enc|->|save to filesink|
                                                        | encode |  |   as jpeg      |
```

at the end both mux output saves files to disk.
What should I add to the pipeline to achieve position tracking at any media player.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure that gstreamer properly signals all the elements that the stream is about to end, when you interrupt it.

usually this is done by sending an EOS event.

```
man gst-launch
   [...]
   -e, --eos-on-shutdown
           Force an EOS event on sources before shutting the pipeline down.
           This is useful to make sure muxers create readable files when a muxing
           pipeline  is  shut  down forcefully via Control-C.
```